# Unhandled exception in Mysql class

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a vb.net class to manage a MySQL database connection and i have a method Connect wich is suposed to assign the connection string to a mysqlconnection variable but i'm always getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Projecto_Aula.exe Additional information: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

**DatabaseManager.vb**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class DatabaseManager
    Private connetionString As String = vbNullString
    Private sqlReader As MySqlDataReader
    Private sqlAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Private sqlCommand As MySqlCommand
    Private sqlConnection As MySqlConnection

    Sub New(ByVal host As String, ByVal user As String, ByVal password As String, Optional ByVal database As String = "requisicoes")
        connetionString = "server=" & host & "; uid=" & user & "; pwd=" & password & "; database=" & database
        MsgBox(connetionString)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Connect()

        If (sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then ''throws exception when run
            MsgBox("Already connected to the database.")
            Return
        End If

        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connetionString.ToString()

        If (connetionString = vbNullString) Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Connection String!")
            Application.Exit()
        End If

        Try
            sqlConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error connecting: " & ex.ToString())
            Application.Exit()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

**MainMenu.vb**

```
Public Class Login

    Public databaseManager As New DatabaseManager("localhost", "root", "", "requisicoes")

    Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        databaseManager.Connect() 'throws exception when run

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Debug the code. Who will create sqlConnection?

Comment: __sqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connetionString)__ in the constructor. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are NOT set (null/Nothing):

```
Private sqlReader As MySqlDataReader
Private sqlAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
Private sqlCommand As MySqlCommand
Private sqlConnection As MySqlConnection
```

You need to create the objects BEFORE you using then:

```
Me.sqlReader = New MySqlDataReader
Me.sqlAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
Me.sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
Me.sqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
```

So in the `Connect()` method create a new `MySqlConnection` and replace "myConnectionString" with a valid connection string.

```
Public Sub Connect()

    Me.sqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("myConnectionString")


    Try
        Me.sqlConnection.Open()
        MsgBox(Me.sqlConnection.State.ToString())
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error connecting: " & ex.ToString())
        Application.Exit()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ur following line of code with this mention code

```
 sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connetionString.ToString()
```

Change to:

```
     sqlConnection.ConnectionString = Convert.ToString(connetionString)
```